# Is there a way to port my Silverlight application to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, silverlight-5.0, porting

I'm working on a project where I need to convert an existing set of solutions to Visual Studio 2017. One of those solution has got some Silverlight application in it. Now, I was able to port all those projects to VS 2017 except the Silverlight ones. While I know that Silverlight applications aren't supported from Visual Studio 2017 and the deadline for Silverlight is decided to be in 2021 as per Microsoft, is there a way we can port the application to VS2017 using a workaround.

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You might try to port to WPF, or Blazor. But that's too broad to discuss.